# DataGridView navigating to next row

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a C# winforms application and I am trying to get a button working that will select the next row in a datagridview after the one curently selected.

The code I have so far is:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    Int32 selectedRowCount = dataGridView1.Rows.GetRowCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected);

    // index out of range on this line
    dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.SelectedRows[selectedRowCount].Index].Selected = true;

    dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = selectedRowCount + 1;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    return;
  }
```

But on running this it throws an exception. Could anyone point out where I may be going wrong. The thrown error is: `Index is out of range`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this:

```
 int nRow;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    nRow = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (nRow < dataGridView1.RowCount )
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[nRow].Selected = false;
        dataGridView1.Rows[++nRow].Selected = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is working to a certain extent. It would like it to deselect the previous row though.

Comment: This is perfect thank you. I see now what I should have been doing.

Answer (score 4):

First, set "**Multiselect**" property of datagridview to **false.**

```
int currentRow = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;
if (currentRow < dataGridView1.RowCount)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[++currentRow].Selected = true;
}
```

It will select the next row in the datagridview.

Answer (score 3):

Select Row and Cell for better solution.
This solution move row indicator on DataGridView.

```
    private void _GotoNext(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int currentRow = DataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;
        if (currentRow < DataGridView1.RowCount - 1)
        {
            DataGridView1.Rows[++currentRow].Cells[0].Selected = true;
        }
    }

    private void _GotoPrev(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int currentRow = DataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;
        if (currentRow > 0)
        {
            DataGridView1.Rows[--currentRow].Cells[0].Selected = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's here:

```
dataGridView1.SelectedRows[selectedRowCount]
```

If you have 3 selected rows then selectedRowCount = 3 and there are three rows with indexes: 0, 1, 2.

You are trying to access #3 which doesn't exist.

Comment: Ah I see. Can you suggest a method to achieve the result im looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

this example to read value cell or column is number 4 of datagridview

```
        int courow = dataGridView1.RowCount-1;
        for (int i=0; i < courow; i++)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this row selection :

First check if no multiselect : number_of_data
Then get the select cell (or row) : row_index

```
private void next_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int number_of_data = dataGridView.SelectedRows.Count;
        if (number_of_data > 1) return;

        int row_index = dataGridView.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;

        if (row_index < dataGridView.RowCount-1)
        {
            dataGridView.Rows[row_index++].Selected = false;
            dataGridView.Rows[row_index].Selected = true;
        }

        // Do something 

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            X = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;//int x;
    }

enter code here  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            this.dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
            dataGridView1.Rows[0].Selected = true;
        }
    }
enter code here  private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       

        if (X < dataGridView1.RowCount)
        {
            if (X != dataGridView1.RowCount - 1)
            {
                dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
                dataGridView1.Rows[++X].Selected = true;

            }
            else
            {
                button2_Click(sender, e);//this else with make it loop 
                X = 0;
            }
        }
       

    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
dgv_PhotoList.Rows[dgv_PhotoList.CurrentRow.Index+1].Selected = true;
```