# How can I read the next DataGridView row?

Tags: c#, datagridview

How can I make this read the DataGridView and SetAttribute? 
I have been doing this:

```
(string)dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index].Cells[0].Value)
```

to read the first row, but I need to read 0, and then the next row (1, after first second etc)

I have looked at this question: [DataGridView navigating to next row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11158044/datagridview-navigating-to-next-row)

But I don't know how to write it.

This is my code to read now:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("pass").SetAttribute("value", (string)dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index].Cells[0].Value);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a for loop to go through all the rows one by one

```
for(int i=0;i<datagrid.Rows.Count;i++){
    val=datagrid[0,i].Value.Tostring();   // 0 is column no
}
```

or a while by manually incrementing  row count..

Comment: Can i write it like that ?             for(int i=0;i<dataGridView1.Rows.Count;i++){
    Int32 val = dataGridView1[i,0].Value;   // 0 is column no im getting error on datagridview1.etc

Comment: yes of course. You can use datagrid1 if it is the name of your controller. I've changed my code a little bit. the column and row order is chaged to "datagrid[0,i]"

What is the exact error you are facing

Comment: That works, but it reads from second row, how to make it reading from what i want row ?

Comment: it starts from the raw no you given in for the var i; if i=0 then will start from first row. if i=1 starts from 2nd one...

Comment: i mean column val = dataGridView1[i, 0] it reads second column

Comment: Change it to [0,i]     first column, then row.  change 0 as you want to match your column

Comment: read the given answer correctly. it should be [0,i]  not [i,0]