# c# move a data grid view up or down using buttons

Tags: c#, datagridview, dataset

I have create a example program of the problem I am currently facing. Due to nature of windows object you cannot simply cast objects or integers into the data grid view as its read only, because of this I'm unable to copy the current position of the dataset and use that postion into the data grid view. I've managed to get the data grid view to display the views selected if a cell is clicked though it cannot navigate using the buttons. An example picture is below;

[image]

As you can see the value in the text box is different to data grid view, my intention is move the selected value from the use of buttons, this would match the same values in text box.

```
    private void fill_table()
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
        try
        {
            connection.ConnectionString = connectionPath;
            connection.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Users", connection);
            SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            dap.Fill(ds);

            bs.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            dgv.DataSource = bs;
            dap.Update(ds);              

            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                object u = dr["Username"];
                string conversion_u = (string)u;
                string decrypted_u = Decrypt(conversion_u.Trim(), password);
                dr["Username"] = decrypted_u;

                object p = dr["Password"];
                string conversion_p = (string)p;
                string decrypted_p = Decrypt(conversion_p.Trim(), password);
                dr["Password"] = decrypted_p;

                object t = dr["Time"];
                string conversion_t = (string)t;
                string decrypted_t = Decrypt(conversion_t.Trim(), password);
                dr["Time"] = decrypted_t;
            }

        }
        catch (SqlException sql)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(sql.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
            connection.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

This is current code for loading the values in data grid view object

```
    private void btnFirst_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (inc != MaxRows + 1)
        {
            inc = 0;
            MaxRows = 0;
            fill_textBoxes();
        }

    }

    private void btnPrevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (inc != MaxRows + 1)
            {
                inc--;
                fill_textBoxes();
            }
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
        {
            DialogResult dlgResult;
            dlgResult = MessageBox.Show(
                    "First record",
                    "Records",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                    MessageBoxIcon.Warning,
                    MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
        }
    }

    private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (inc != MaxRows - 1)
        {
            inc++;
            fill_textBoxes();
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("No more records");
    }

    private void btnLast_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (inc != MaxRows - 1)
        {
            inc = MaxRows - 1;
            fill_textBoxes();

        }
    }
    private void dgv_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex];

            txtdeuser.Text = row.Cells["Username"].Value.ToString();
            txtdepass.Text = row.Cells["Password"].Value.ToString();
            dtp.Text = row.Cells["Time"].Value.ToString();
        }
    }
```

This is current code for navigation for the text boxes and to change the fields if value is clicked in data grid view.

Comment: If I understand your questino correctly, you want to highlight the row in  `datagridview` based on your navigation?

Comment: Turns out my answer was as simple as this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11158044/datagridview-navigating-to-next-row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres the code I managed to get it working

```
    pos = dgv.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

    private void btnFirst_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (inc != MaxRows + 1)
        {
            inc = 0;
            MaxRows = 0;
            fill_textBoxes();

            if (pos < dgv.RowCount)
            {
                dgv.Rows[pos].Selected = false;
                dgv.Rows[pos = 0].Selected = true;
            }
        }           
    }
    private void btnPrevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (inc != MaxRows + 1)
            {
                inc--;
                fill_textBoxes();

                if (pos < dgv.RowCount)
                {
                    dgv.Rows[pos].Selected = false;
                    dgv.Rows[--pos].Selected = true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
        {
            DialogResult dlgResult;
            dlgResult = MessageBox.Show(
                    "First record",
                    "Records",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                    MessageBoxIcon.Warning,
                    MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
        }
    }

    private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (inc != MaxRows - 1)
        {
            inc++;
            fill_textBoxes();

            if (pos < dgv.RowCount)
            {
                dgv.Rows[pos].Selected = false;
                dgv.Rows[++pos].Selected = true;
            }
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("No more records");
    }

    private void btnLast_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (inc != MaxRows - 1)
        {
            inc = MaxRows - 1;
            fill_textBoxes();

            if (pos < dgv.RowCount)
            {
                dgv.Rows[pos].Selected = false;
                dgv.Rows[pos = MaxRows - 1].Selected = true;
            }
        }
    }
```